# Binding ko.observableArray<string>([]) to <select>

Tags: javascript, select, knockout.js

I am trying to bind a string array to a `<select>`. I try to bind it initially but keep getting a message that `someOptions` is undefined. I have try to move it in "Load Button" click event but it didn't seem to work either. Anyone has any idea where went wrong?

My Code:

```js
function CarsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    //Data

    self.someOptions = ko.observableArray<string>([]);
    self.myOption = ko.observable<string>("Toyota");

    //Operations
    self.initData = function () {
        //$.get('/Home/GetCars', function (data) {
        var data = [
            "Mercedes-Benz",
            "Toyota",
            "Huyndai" ];
            self.someOptions(data);
        //});
    }
    //self.initData()
}

ko.applyBindings(new CarsViewModel());
```

```html
<div>
    <button data-bind="click: initData">Load data</button>
    <h4>Preview</h4>
    <p>
        <select data-bind="options: someOptions, value: myOption"></select><br />
        <!-- ko with: myOption -->
        A <span data-bind="text: myOption"></span>.
        <!-- /ko -->
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works, just strip both `<string>` tokens and both `<!-- ... -->` blocks out. https://jsfiddle.net/6w6Lcbtm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in your code:

- There is no such thing as `observable<string>` or generics in javascript proper, you should get rid of it;
- You do `with: myOption` but inside it you refer to `myOption` *again*. Use either `$data` or get rid of the `with`, or use `if` if you want to show/hide the entire thing optionally;
- You set the initial value of `myOption` but that's confusing / useless, as the rendering of the `select` will overwrite it to empty string on load;

With those things fixed everything works:

```js
function CarsViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.someOptions = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.myOption = ko.observable("");

    self.initData = function () {
      var data = ["Mercedes-Benz", "Toyota", "Huyndai" ];
      self.someOptions(data);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new CarsViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div>
    <button data-bind="click: initData">Load data</button>
    <h4>Preview</h4>
    <p>
        <select data-bind="options: someOptions, value: myOption"></select>
        <br />
        <!-- ko if: !!myOption() -->
        A <span data-bind="text: myOption"></span>.
        <!-- /ko -->
    </p>
</div>
```